# Which Pin is NC, NO, COM in this relay module

Tags: relay

[image]

Above is an image of a relay module but the problem is the pin name is written in the chinese language so it is difficult for me to figure out the name of the all 3 pins. So, Please clarify which pin is NC, NO, COM?

Comment: Did you search for the datasheet for the relay? The part number is clearly printed on the relay. Did you try using your multimeter?

Answer (score 4):

One second on google gave me this:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Google Translate has a mode for translating from simplified Chinese to English where you can manually draw (using the mouse) the Chinese symbols and see the resulting English text. Using this I was able to obtain this result.

[image]

Comment: Pretty cool, actually. I never tried that.

Answer (score 1):

Centre is COM left is NO right is NC. Try google translate next time. Translate English to Chinese put in "normally open" and "normally closed".